# React Native, AWS, Error only on Android "TypeError: Cannot read Property 'handle' of null"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda

I ran into a bug whenever I run my React Native app on an Android device (physical and emulator). Yet, no problem at all on iOS. These functions are supposed to scan the database table for user handles and return an object if the handle already exists.

This is what the error looks like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of null
at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:7:36)
```

I'm using React Native, AWS Lambda, and EXPO.

This code lives within `dbfunctions.js` on the front end.

```
export async function scanHandles(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let { auth } = store.getState()


    let reqBody = {
      userId: auth.user.username,
      handle: auth.handle_update,
    }

    let path = '/u/scan-handle'
    let myInit = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: reqBody,
    }

    console.log('myInit', myInit)
    console.log('handle', auth.handle_update)

    API.get(apiName, path, myInit)

      .then((resp) => {
        // if false, then handle does not exist
        // if true, then handle already exists
        resolve(resp)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Scan Handle', error)
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

Console logging `auth.handle_update` does print out the expected string. `myInit` also prints out the expected object.

On the back end, I'm using this for my scan:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-west-1" });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let e = JSON.parse(event.body);

  var params = {
    TableName: event.stageVariables.user,
    FilterExpression: "handle = :handle",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":handle": e.handle }
  };

  docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR:", err);
      let response = {
        statusCode: err.statusCode,
        headers: {},
        body: JSON.stringify(err)
      };
      callback(response);
    }
    if (data.Count >= 1) {
      // if user name exists
      // call back handle exists response

      let handleExistsResponse = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ Success: true })
      };
      callback(null, handleExistsResponse);
    } else {
      let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ Success: false })
      };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  });
};
```

Any idea as to why this would work on iOS and not Android?

EDIT:

Upon further testing,  `let e = JSON.parse(event.body)` is returning `null`. So I console logged `event` and got a big ol object. Within this object, I found `body` and it's still `null`. So the body object isn't being passed it properly. Still confused about it working on iOS and not Android.

Answer (score 0):

Did it!
Okay so API.get doesn't like body's being passed in. Instead, it wants a query parameter. So the lambda params looks like:

```
 var params = {
    TableName: event.stageVariables.user,
    FilterExpression: "handle = :handle",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ":handle": event["queryStringParameters"]["handle"]
    }
  };
```

And the front end function is:

```
export async function scanHandles(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let { auth } = store.getState()
    let handle = auth.handle_update

    let path = `/u/scan-handle?handle=${handle}`
    let myInit = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }

    API.get(apiName, path, myInit)

      .then((resp) => {
        // if false, then handle does not exist
        // if true, then handle already exists
        resolve(resp)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Scan Handle', error)
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

Works on both iOS and Android. Wonder why it wasn't working before?